# Get static method of parent object

Tags: c#, reflection, static-methods

Having an issue with getting a static method from a parent object.  Examine the following code:

```
var objType = typeof(myClass);   // myClass is a ChildClass object
var methods = objType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
```

Parent Class:

```
public class ParentClass {
    public static T GrabStuff<T>(string values) {
        GrabStuff<T>(values, false);
    }

    // ---- Updated
    public static T GrabStuff<T>(string values, bool isSomething) {
        // TODO: Do Stuff
    }
    // ---- Updated
}
```

Child Class:

```
public class ChildClass : ParentClass {
}
```

Methods is returning and array of 0 objects.

Am I doing something wrong here to pull a list of static methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify `BindingFlags.Public`:

```
var objType = typeof(ChildClass);
var methods = objType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | 
                                 BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | 
                                 BindingFlags.Public);
```

With this change the `MethodInfo`'s for `GrabStuff`, `Equals` and `ReferenceEquals` are returned.

Comment: Yes, this worked.  However, how would I pull a method that is overloaded?  This worked, when I added the BindingFlags.Public.  However, the example above doesn't show it, but GrabStuff is overloaded and I am getting a "Ambiguous match found." when I use the GetMethod function.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you update your question with some code that reproduces this?

Comment: Sean, your updated example works for me (4 methods returned) - no repro here with .NET 4

Comment: Yes, it works fine for GetMethods.  I was asking when I pull the method by name with GetMethod.  I suppose, since it's overloaded I have to use GetMethods and grab the method I need via it's index?

Comment: You would have to uniquely identify the method - since the name is not enough in this case you would have to use the `GetMethod` overload that allows you to specify the parameter types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You must specify `BindingFlags.Public` in addition to `BindingFlags.Static`:

```
var objType = typeof(ChildClass);
var methods = objType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```